# Android + JSON Securing against decompilation?

Tags: android, json, security, obfuscation

I want to be a able to securely send data from my Android App to my server using HTTPS and JSON.

With HTTPS i am secure against sniffing but not against decompilation so i will also use Proguard to Obfuscate.

My question is with JSON being a plain text method of sending data a skilled decompiler will be able to work out what is being sent and received. So what is a better way of sending this data - If i assume that at some point someone will decompile the APK or JAR (depending on how i launch the program).

I could obfuscate the JSON

```
"x":{"xx":12345678}
```

But again i think it will just be a matter of time before someone works out that i am trying to send a time code etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well... you can't.  Sorry.  If you could figure this one out, the music and movie industry would make you a hero.

Comment: Haha, OK. so instead of app-side code i will have to figure a way to do this on the server side.

Comment: If you do need client-side information, you could try obsfucating your intent.  If you need time information, for example, you could have the client send location information, or do a IP lookup for location and figure out his time zone.

Comment: Yeah, that's what i am thinking. Adding random and useless data that has seeming usefulness and then discarding this data server side to mask the data i actually need. More security by obscurity but i guess it has to be done

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to prevent decompilation. Obfuscation makes the decompiled results harder to use but a dedicated black hat will still be able to use that.

Comment: Exactly, so how do i create sensitive data on the app and send it to a server without that data being read OR the method for which that sensitive data is created being discovered?

Comment: You could use asymmetric encryption (RSA is most common) where your application only has the public key... you encrypt the data with the public key and the server has the private key to decrypt it. I'm not certain this would make things much more secure than just using https (though it would prevent a man-in-the-middle attack).

Comment: but by decompilation the black hat would see my data before putting it through the RSA encryption. SSL (i believe) is good enough for the transmission, it's the data creation that i need/want to protect.

Comment: You're correct, but in an open system, you'll never get complete protection. Under Android, anyone with just a little knowledge can copy your apk off the device and pass it through a disassembler that produces pretty readable assembly code. I don't think anyone has successfully generated Java from this yet, but the assembly is more than enough for 1 person -- and it only takes 1 person to share your secrets to the world :(

Answer (score 0):

The best combination I've found is the [DojoToolkit](http://www.dojotoolkit.org) and the Closure Compiler in Advanced Mode.

Closure in Advanced Mode makes JavaScript code almost impossible to reverse-engineer, even after passing through a beautifier.  Once your JavaScript code is obfuscated beyond any recognition and any possibility to reverse-engineer, your HTML won't disclose much of your secrets.

This link for using the Dojo Toolkit with the Closure Compiler in Advanced Mode for mobile applications:

http://dojo-toolkit.33424.n3.nabble.com/file/n2636749/Using_the_Dojo_Toolkit_with_the_Closure_Compiler.pdf?by-user=t

If you use the Closure Compiler, you can then throw in an encryption engine writting in JavaScript, then encrypt your JSON data.  With the level obfuscation provided by the Closure Compiler, it will be very difficult for people to reverse-engineer your code to discover the key you use to decrypt.